# Sending Email error: An asynchronous module or handler still on hold when the asynchronous operation is complete

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I try to send email but I have An asynchronous module or handler still on hold when the asynchronous operation is complete. I don't know what to do? thanks

My ASPX markup:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" 
         CodeFile="fotokopiTalebiGorSayfasi.aspx.cs" 
         Inherits="fotokopiTalebiGorSayfasi" Async="true" %>
```

My `aspx.cs`:

```
public void client_SendCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
}

public bool Email()
{
    try
    {

        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("x.x.x.x", 25);
        NetworkCredential credential = new NetworkCredential(mailAdres, mailSifre, "DPTDOMAIN");
        client.Credentials = credential; 

        MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
        message.From = new MailAddress(mailAdres,"y.m");
        message.To.Add(new MailAddress(mailAdres));

        message.Subject = "Fotokopi Talep";
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;
        message.Body = "talep onaylandı";

        // client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        // client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.SendAsync(message, 1);
        client.SendCompleted += new SendCompletedEventHandler(client_SendCompleted);
        // client.Send(message);

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
        //throw new Exception("Mail Gönderirken Bir Hata Oluştu.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a template for an email.  I helps if you use smtp.port=25;.

```
  try 
  { 
           MailMessage msg = new MailMessage ();
           MailAddress fromAdd = new MailAddress("fromemail@email.com");
           msg.[To].Add("toemail@email.com");
           msg.Subject = "Choose Session Members";
           msg.From = fromAdd;
           msg .IsBodyHtml = true;
           msg.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;
           msg .BodyEncoding = Encoding.Default;
           msg.Body = "<center><table><tr><td><h1>Your Message</h1><br/><br/></td></tr>";
           msg.Body = msg.Body + "</table></center>";
           SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient ("smtp.yourserver.com", "25");
           smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
           smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
           smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("yourname@yourserver.com", "password");
           smtpClient .DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
           smtpClient.Send(msg);
           smtpClient.Dispose();
        }
    catch (exception ex){
        Label1.Text  = ex.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: I tried it earlier , and it has error: "Remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure"